# V8 compile error in Javascript

Tags: node.js

EDIT: Don't bother with this question, it is irrelevant, waiting moderation.

I cannot compile the following:

```
var argStr = arguments[0];
var options = {};
if (argStr){
    options = JSON.parse(argStr);
}
options.cb = function(port){
  // Send the port back to the master so that 
  process.send({
    pid: process.pid, 
    type: 'init',
    port: port
  });
};
require('./x2ProxyService')(options);
```

Node gives the following error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
at Object.parse (native)
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\formwork\FRFcour\portal\controller\fwProxyServerLaunch.js:5:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

It appears to be failing on "JSON" but I don't know why.

Comment: is `argStr` valid JSON?

Comment: Total fail on my part. The module was being called as a child_process but --debug-brk was not passed in correctly. So the process did not wait for the debugger, and the value passed to .parse() was actually invalid. I though it was due to a compilation error because the column number pointed at a funny position. It is a bad question and should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to check to see if args is already a javascript object, then if it is a string.

If it's a string we try to parse it. if that doesn't work we really have a problem....

```
var argStr = arguments[0],
    argeType = typeof argStr;
if (argeType === 'object') {
    options = argStr;
} else if (argeType === 'string') {
    try {
        options = JSON.parse(argStr);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('argStr is neith an object, nor JSON');
        console.error(e);
        return
    }
} else {
    console.error('ummm houston we have a problem... ERRRZ!');
}
```

Comment: In case you really really need to solve that 'huston we have a problem' scenario, check out [jsonrepair](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jsonrepair) module... works wonders and easy to get it going

Answer (score 0):

You should always wrap `JSON.parse()` in `try-catch` statement. The value of `argStr` is not a valid JSON, check it.

```
if (argStr) {
    try {
        options = JSON.parse(argStr);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('JSON error: ' + error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally this particular error occurs because the value you're trying to parse (`argStr`) is already a JavaScript object, not a string.